# Unexpected padding at top of ionic menu bar on iPhones

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic2

The menu/title bar for my ionic 2 app looks fine on Android phones and fine on the web emulator for iOS and Android (i.e. there is an equal amount of space above and below the text in the bar) but on iPhones there is an extra @20px of white space at the top of the menu/title bar.

The ionic code I am using for the menu/title bar is:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon class="menu-burger-icon" name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title><img src="img/logo.png" height="14"></ion-title>
  <ion-buttons end>
    {{theUserData.viewCount}}<img src="img/tiny-v.png" height="12" style="margin-left:3px;margin-bottom: 0px;">
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: maybe that 20px are the iOS status bar? may you share a screenshot?

Comment: I have added a screen grab. It isn't the status bar.

Comment: maybe more source code can help (but I'm not an expert on ionic)

Comment: What version of Ionic2 are you using?

Comment: Not sure how to check but I think it is Beta 10

Comment: Well there are a few things we can try to fix this... the first one is to change the navbar because now in `beta 10` the `*navbar` is not used anymore. You now need to wrap it inside `<ion-header></ion-header>` like you can see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/navbar/Navbar/). Also, please check that you're calling the `StatusBar.styleDefault()` when platform is ready, because there were [some issues](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6171) related to the top padding when that method is not called.

Comment: Excellent! That has done it. Thanks.